# Inconsistent arithmetic of TimeSeries with non-equally spaced data?

Tags: core-language, time-series

Consider the following non-equally spaced `TimeSeries`:

```
ts = TimeSeries[
   Prepend[ConstantArray[1, 99], 
    0], {Prepend[(100 + Range[99])/100, 0]}];
ListLinePlot[ts, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}]
```

[image]

Visually, geometry suggests the `Mean` ought to be roughly 3/4. However,

```
Mean[ts] 
(*99/100*)
```

This is the same as `Mean[ts["Values"]]`. In other words, `Mean` is computed using the underlying values, assuming they're equally spaced... even if they're not.

In contrast, `Mean@TimeSeriesResample@ts` returns $149/200\approx 3/4$. By resampling with equal spacing, which roughly corresponds to applying `Mean` to the underlying continuous interpolating function, we get the expected result.

As a result, my initial hypothesis of how functions are applied to `TimeSeries` was `f_[t_TimeSeries]:=f_[t["Values"]]`.

Now consider `Differences`, which provides a counterexample:

```
Differences[ts]["Values"][[1 ;; 3]]
(*{1/101, 1/101, 0}*)

Differences[ts["Values"]][[1 ;; 3]]
(*{1, 0, 0}*)
```

Unlike `Mean`, it appears `Differences` of a `TimeSeries` somehow takes into account the spacing of the datapoints.

So my question is:

- Is there a consistent rule for how functions (such as `Mean` or `Differences`) are computed for `TimeSeries` with unequally-spaced data?

Personally, my intuition is that applying a function to a `TimeSeries` ought to roughly correspond to applying that function to the underlying `InterpolatingFunction` of the data. However, that's debatable, and `Mean` clearly wasn't implemented that way.

This has caused some unexpected results while I was working with unequally-spaced `TimeSeries`.

Answer (score 1):

The Mean[] you're looking for is

```
1/2 NIntegrate[ts[t], {t, 0, 2}]
(* 0.747499 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the rule you are looking for but:
- if the function to be applied does not care about seriality of the data but operates on a collection, like Mean, then it will be applied to values
- if the function cares in which order the data comes and in what steps, like Differences and Accumulate, then it will resample the data to ensure consistent step.